# Why the slide in overlay has error when defining inline css?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style=margin-top:250px>
<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

This code is works the way i want. (There is a overlay effect slides from top to bottom)

[image]

I want to set an inline position to reuse the code but when I change this code
`<div class="overlay"></div>` to `<div class="overlay" style="bottom:100%"></div>`
The result is as shown below.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: And what is your desired effect? Your inline style Bottom 100% overwrites your hover style in css.

Comment: I want to reuse .overlay class to overlay slides on different sides (top,bottom,left,right), how do I set bottom,left.right separately?

Comment: add more classes. And add / change desired styles in it... E.g. class="overlay bottom" and in your css define .overlay.bottom:hover { bottom: 100%; }

Comment: It's work for me thank you.

Comment: You can self-answer to share how you fix it !

Comment: I have shared my solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the style.

```
.overlay.bottom {
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

and change code in body to

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay bottom"></div>
</div>
```

and now we can reuse .overlay class to overlay slides on different sides (top,left,right) by following the previous method.